# Cannot change the height of a uilabel in a custom uitableviewcell

Tags: ios, uitableview, size

I am trying to change height of the uilabel in a custom uitableviewcell in -

```
    (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath.
```

The problem is that the height of the uilabel is not changing unless i scroll the tableview down and back.

Anyone knows how to solve this problem?

Answer (score 0):

You can try

```
-(CGFloat)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView heightForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath;
{
return labelHeight;
}
```

height for row value is greater than the label height.

Comment: No, i don't want to set the height of the cell to be the height of label. I simply want to change the size of the label inside the tableviewcell. The problem is the size of the label does not change unless i scroll the tableview down and back.

Comment: what is your label height?

Comment: like change it to 20 in the method cellForRowAtIndexPath

Comment: {
    HXRContentTableViewCell *cell = [self.tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier_ContentCell forIndexPath:indexPath];
    HXRContent *currentContent = [self.contents objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
    UIFont *textFont = [UIFont fontWithName:@"Arial" size:14];
    CGSize size = [currentContent.text sizeWithFont:textFont constrainedToSize:CGSizeMake(300, 300) lineBreakMode:NSLineBreakByWordWrapping];
    cell.label_Text.frame = CGRectMake(cell.label_Text.frame.origin.x, cell.label_Text.frame.origin.y, size.width, size.height);
    return cell;
}

Comment: instead of size.height you can take directly 20 and check it

Comment: yeah, but thats not the problem. the PROBLEM is the size of the label won't refresh get repaint to the PROPER size unless I scroll down the tableview and scroll back. That means i have to make the cell disappears and the label will show the proper size when it appears again.

Answer (score 0):

For multiline labels you need set

```
cell.textLabel.numberOfLines = 0;
```

and then

```
[cell.textLabel sizeToFit];
```

Comment: the point is the label won't refresh the size unless i scroll the tableview down and up.